# How to use google analytics for win phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, google-analytics

I have a win phone and I got a new requirement to put google analytic to log app events.
I added everything I found over net but my client saying that he is not seeing any log. So what I using is

```
 GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SetStartSession(true);
```

Used this line of code on app startup. And than

```
   public void SendEvent(string category, string action, string label, int value)
    {
        GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendEvent(category, action, label, value);
    }
```

this method to log events. Is there something wrong I am doing?

Comment: Hi, may you are having wrong trackingId in 'analytics.xml' file. Please check with that once.

Comment: Id I am using is correct, can you just tell me that my code is correct or not?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Try this, just remove SetStartSession(true) and directly try to call SendEvent().

Comment: When you created a "Property" in Google Analytics, did you make sure it was the Mobile App type and *not* Website?